# Make second api call when there is no error on the first using Axios in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I have three API calls which should be dependent on one another. The second API call should trigger only when the first succeeds.

With my current implementation, I'm getting a CORS error when the first API call is made and was able to catch the error in the `catch` block. However, I'm seeing that the *second* and *third* APIs calls are made irrespective of the error that got caught in the *first* API call.

Could anyone please advise?

```
const firstApiCall = async() => {
  try {
    await axios.post(
      process.env.FIRST_API,
      payload
    );
  ]
} catch (err) {
  console.log(`err`, err);
}
};


const secondApiCall = async() => {
  try {
    await axios.post(
      process.env.SECOND_API,
      payload

    }
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(`err`, err);
  }
};

const thirdApiCall = async() => {
  try {
    await axiosInstance.patch(
      process.env.THIRD_API,
      payload
    );
  } catch (err) {
    console.log('err', err);
  }
};

firstApiCall();
secondApiCall();
thirdApiCall();
```

Comment: If you `catch` the error and do not return or set any status outside of each function, how is the next one to know that a previous one failed (event if you `await` each one)?

Comment: Do you recommend to `throw` the error in catch block? @crashmstr

Comment: Only `catch` when you can either handle the problem or need to not let an exception go outside of that code. So `try`/`catch` at a higher level or return some success or failure.

Answer (score 1):

You're calling the functions synchronously when you need to do it asynchronously:

```
 async function performTasks() {
    await firstApiCall();
    await secondApiCall();
    await thirdApiCall();
  }
  performTasks();
```

Comment: @coderpc Are you sure that worked? Your code does not show any way for `secondApiCall` to know that there was a failure in `firstApiCall`.

Comment: @crashmstr I celebrated too early, it did not work.

Answer (score 1):

`async` `await` functions work only in their local scope.
For example:

```
const myFunc = async() => {
  try{
    //...
    await foo();
    //All the code below will be blocked till 
    //the promise return by foo function is resolved
  }
  catch{
    //...
  }
}

const main = () => {
  myFunc();
  otherFunc();
  //Other function calls
  //Regardless of using async await in myFunc, 
  //the code bellow myFunc will be executed as
  //async await will work only in myFunc block scope
}

main()
```

What you can do is, use `async` `await` inside the main function, so that the functions would be called in an order

```
const main = async () => {
  await myFunc();
  await otherFunc();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the ES6 Promise implementation approacg. Therefore you should take a look to this ressource : [Promise][1]

With the promise approach you can react at each step / each API call.
[1]: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then